# PowerShell - Read in JSOn file, use string interpolation

Tags: json, string, powershell, string-interpolation

I have a JSON file, called data.json with contents:

```
{
    "environment": "${environment}",
    "url": "https://${environment}.example.com"
}
```

I have a PowerShell script, where I am attempting to read in the JSON file and use string interpolation to substitute the value of the PowerShell `$environment` variable into the JSON file.

script.ps1:

```
$environment = "qa"
$json = Get-Content -Path ".\data.json"
$formatted = Invoke-Expression "`"${json}`""
Write-host $formatted
```

When I run this, I can't seem to get around problems with the value being sent to Invoke-Expression as being null or invalid character ':' from the JSON.

Is there an easier/better way of trying to read in a JSON file and perform string interpolation on it?

I am trying to avoid using `ExpandString()`, string concatenation, `string.Replace()` and `-f`.

The end goal, I'm hoping to have a Json PowerShell object (using `ConvertFrom-Json`) to be:

```
{
    "environment": "qa",
    "url": "https://qa.example.com"
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I am trying to avoid using `ExpandString()`, string concatenation, `string.Replace()` and `-f`" - why?

Comment: `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()` sounds exactly like what you want - why the aversion?

Comment: @pdalbe01, are you concerned that using ExpandString() could create a `code injection` type of ploy?

Comment: I'm using this technique to dynamically transform JSON for different development environments. And I'm trying to put the "things that need transformation" in the data.json file and the "values of the things" in other JSON files. The "values of the things" are read in and use `Invoke-Expression` to create variables at run-time. This gives us great flexibility as we could start creating variables in JSON and their related string interpolation tokens without code changes.

Comment: Ex: repos.json is `[ { "repo": "app1", "branch": "master", "variable": "app1MasterHash" } ]`. This would create a variable $app1MasterHash and then I can use this in data.json.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$environment = 'qa'
$json = Get-Content -Path '.\data.json' -Raw  # be sure to add -Raw switch
$formatted = Invoke-Expression "@""`n$json`n""@"
Write-Host $formatted
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Bill_Stewart and @Mathias R. Jessen - I explored a bit more and it seems like `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()` works. To be honest, I'm not sure what I read yesterday that led me to believe that ExpandString() would not work. Thank you for your help, much appreciated.